# Always show horizontal scrollbar in JavaFX-2 TableView

Tags: javafx-2, scrollbar, tableview

I have a `TableView` in JavaFx-2 that's inside a `SplitPane` and I would like to always show the horizontal scrollbar for the TableView.

The TableView has multiple columns that are wider than the width of the entire table. When the TableView has at least one row filled, the scrollbar is displayed and I can scroll across the table. **However, when the table is empty, the scrollbar does not appear and I'm stuck on whichever columns were last visible.**

Comment: doesn't seem to be supported: the scrollbars are completely under the (package private!) control of table's skin/virtualContainer, nothing to do from the outside (tried to force their visibility to true, to no avail). You might consider filing a bug/feature request in fx issue tracker